# Play SVG when entering viewport - Browser Support?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have the following script that plays my SVGs when they scroll into view (i have several of these SVGs on the page). This works perfectly but only in Firefox! Is this the correct way to do it or is there a better code that will work on other browsers? Ideally, if it can't work on IE, and i am expecting this, then the SVG would just appear like an image and not animated. But i would expect it to work in all other browsers!

```
<div id="arrow-2id" class="arrow-2 leftarrows">
            <!--START ARROW 2-->
                <svg id="arrow2svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 265.009 303.044">
                <script type="text/javascript">
    
                var diva2 = document.getElementById("arrow-2id");
                
                window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
                  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= diva2.offsetTop - -500) {
                    diva2.classList.add("play");
                  }
                  
                 }
                );
                </script>
                
                <mask id="arrow2-mask1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <path d="M272.304,11.13c-85-31.5-421.5,178.5-175,268.5"/>
                </mask>
                
                <mask id="arrow2-mask2" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <path d="M-3.696,293.63
                    c130.667-12.167,130.667,23.5,58.5-89.5"/>
                </mask>
                
                <path mask="url(#arrow2-mask1)" fill="#42A8FC" d="M74.443,277.599c-22.03-9.911-41.892-24.317-56.394-41.811c-32.086-38.702-16.961-81.441,14.377-119.45
                    c8.258-9.874,27.106-28.748,31.125-32.337C95.94,55.065,133.39,29.76,173.667,13.682c21.596-8.622,49.867-18.374,71.02-11.181
                    c10.227,3.479,20.322,12.379,20.322,14.696c-0.002,2.317-8.945-0.005-10.693-0.368c-5.762-1.199-13.512-0.332-19.262,0.301
                    c-22.932,2.51-47.227,13.269-68.383,23.897c-60.319,27.104-104.662,75.694-105.099,75.646
                    c-12.522,12.951-23.527,26.688-32.052,40.988c-32.137,53.904,3.738,93.021,50.723,109.687
                    C91.345,270.88,88.917,283.693,74.443,277.599z"/>
                    
                    <path mask="url(#arrow2-mask2)" fill="#42A8FC" d="M74.443,277.599c-20.021,1.14-40.042,2.28-60.062,3.422c-16.744,0.952-18.679,22.91-2.629,21.996
                    c30.077-1.713,60.152-3.425,90.23-5.14c8.539-0.484,17.633-7.912,13.074-16.089c-13.158-23.591-26.316-47.181-39.471-70.771
                    c-6.476-11.604-30.8-2.861-23.525,10.185c8.394,15.048,19.787,31.097,28.182,46.146c5.811,8.531,5.436,9.656,5.436,9.656
                    L74.443,277.599z"/>
                
                </svg>
                
                <style>
                
                    
                .play #arrow2-mask1 path {
                    fill: none;
                    stroke: white;
                    stroke-width: 29;
                    stroke-dasharray: 478.362 478.362;
                    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                    animation: brush2a 2s linear ;
                    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                }
                .play #arrow2-mask2 path {
                    fill: none;
                    stroke: white;
                    stroke-width: 29;
                    stroke-dasharray: 203.128 203.128;
                    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                    animation: brush2b 2s linear ;
                    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                }
                @keyframes brush2a {
                      0% { stroke-dashoffset: 478.362; }
                     25% { stroke-dashoffset: 478.362; }
                     75% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
                    100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
                }
                @keyframes brush2b {
                      0% { stroke-dashoffset: 203.128; }
                     80% { stroke-dashoffset: 203.128; }
                    100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
                }
                </style>
                <!--END ARROW 2-->
                </div>
```

Comment: I wonder if that because the script is inside the SVG.

Comment: I tried moving the script outside the SVG, it doesn't appear to make any difference.

Comment: I don't see a code issue. The animation works in chrome and edge and the event handler is being bound. So it's likely something to do with code you don't show here.